# How does push method work on head Node in SinglyLinkedList

Tags: javascript, class, data-structures, singly-linked-list

I can't wrap my head around how does Head also changes whenever assigning a new Node to Tail.
Do I miss something important about how Class works?
Please explain in detail to me.

```
 class Node {
    constructor(val){
        this.val = val
        this.next = null
    }
 }

class SinglyLinkedList {
    constructor(){
        this.head = null
        this.tail = null
        this.length = 0
    }
    push(val){
        let newNode = new Node(val)
        if(!this.head){
            this.head = newNode 
            this.tail = this.head
        }else{
            this.tail.next = newNode // <-- this line
            this.tail = newNode
        }
        this.length++
        return this
    }
}
 let list = new SinglyLinkedList()
 slist.push(1)
 slist.push(2)
 slist.push(3)

 console.log(JSON.stringify(list))
//output {"head":{"val":1,"next":{"val":2,"next":
// {"val":3,"next":null}}},"tail":{"val":3,"next":null},"length":3}
```

Doesn't Head only get the first Node object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might help to visualise this.

When `let list = new SinglyLinkedList()` has executed we can picture the state like this:

```
slist
  │
  ▼
┌────────────┐
│ head: null │
│ tail: null │
│ length: 0  │
└────────────┘
```

Now let's see what happens when `slist.push(1)` is called. While executing that method, `this` will be `slist`. First `newNode` is created as `new Node(val)`:

```
this
slist             newNode
  │                 │
  ▼                 ▼
┌────────────┐    ┌────────────┐
│ head: null │    │ val:  1    │
│ tail: null │    │ next: null │
│ length: 0  │    └────────────┘
└────────────┘
```

As `this.head` is `null`, `!this.head` is a truthy expression, so the `if` block gets executed. `this.head = newNode` results in this state:

```
this
slist             newNode
  │                 │
  ▼                 ▼
┌────────────┐    ┌────────────┐
│ head: ────────► │ val:  1    │
│ tail: null │    │ next: null │
│ length: 0  │    └────────────┘
└────────────┘
```

After `this.tail = this.head` executes, we get this:

```
this
slist             newNode
  │                 │
  ▼                 ▼
┌────────────┐    ┌────────────┐
│ head: ────────► │ val:  1    │
│ tail: ────────► │ next: null │
│ length: 0  │    └────────────┘
└────────────┘
```

And finally, the `length` property is incremented. `return this` is executed, but that return value is not used by the caller. So the caller sees this:

```
slist (returned)
  │
  ▼
┌────────────┐    ┌────────────┐
│ head: ────────► │ val:  1    │
│ tail: ────────► │ next: null │
│ length: 1  │    └────────────┘
└────────────┘
```

With the next call of `push`, we again get a `newNode`:

```
this
slist                               newNode
  │                                   │
  ▼                                   ▼
┌────────────┐    ┌────────────┐    ┌────────────┐
│ head: ────────► │ val:  1    │    │ val:  2    │
│ tail: ────────► │ next: null │    │ next: null │
│ length: 1  │    └────────────┘    └────────────┘
└────────────┘
```

This time `head` is not `null` and so we get into the `else` block. There we execute `this.tail.next = newNode`, which is what you asked about. `this` references the list object (the first box in the diagram), `this.tail` references a node object (the second box in the diagram), and `this.tail.next` is the property that is currently `null` but gets a new reference via the assignment. After the assignment that `next` property references `newNode`:

```
this
slist                               newNode
  │                                   │
  ▼                                   ▼
┌────────────┐    ┌────────────┐    ┌────────────┐
│ head: ────────► │ val:  1    │    │ val:  2    │
│ tail: ────────► │ next: ────────► │ next: null │
│ length: 1  │    └────────────┘    └────────────┘
└────────────┘
```

And finally `this.tail = newNode` and `this.length++` are executed:

```
this
slist                               newNode
  │                                   │
  ▼                                   ▼
┌────────────┐    ┌────────────┐    ┌────────────┐
│ head: ────────► │ val:  1    │    │ val:  2    │
│ tail: ───────┐  │ next: ────────► │ next: null │
│ length: 2  │ │  └────────────┘    └────────────┘
└────────────┘ │                      ▲
               └──────────────────────┘
```

Repeat this process for the call of `slist.push(3)` and the caller ends up with:

```
slist
  │
  ▼
┌────────────┐    ┌────────────┐    ┌────────────┐    ┌────────────┐
│ head: ────────► │ val:  1    │    │ val:  2    │    │ val:  3    │
│ tail: ───────┐  │ next: ────────► │ next: ────────► │ next: null │
│ length: 2  │ │  └────────────┘    └────────────┘    └────────────┘
└────────────┘ │                                         ▲
               └─────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: did you generate this or drew this by hand?

Comment: Just old style typing & copy/paste

Answer (score 0):

This is the case when the list is empty and the first item is added. - `if(!this.head)`

Comment: I know. I just want to know why this.head value also changes when ELSE happens.

Comment: @JimChang you have made a comment on the line which isn't in else block